# What does Dolores Umbridge lack in her personality?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

We know from [Pottermore](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/2kvcx0/phoenix_is_out_on_pottermore/clp258m) that Dolores Umbridge has a very short wand:

> Wand: Birch and dragon heartstring, **eight inches long**

Also, that short wands tend to choose wizards with something lacking in their character/personality.

> Most wands will be in the range of between nine and fourteen inches.
>   **While I have sold extremely short wands (eight inches and under)** and
>   very long wands (over fifteen inches), these are exceptionally rare.
>   In the latter case, a physical peculiarity demanded the excessive wand
>   length. However, **abnormally short wands usually select those in whose
>   character something is lacking**, rather than because they are
>   physically undersized (many small witches and wizards are chosen by
>   longer wands). - [Garrick Ollivander, wandmaker](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit)

We know for sure that two things Umbridge lacks is empathy (she is really sadistic) and good taste (here I'm translating from German, I hope it means what it is supposed to mean!).

Now my speculation: because of her narrow world view and because of the way she seeks and uses power, I had the impression that she must also be lacking self-esteem and/or self-confidence. It's common that people become narrow-minded and power-seeking (not necessarily to the extent Umbridge does) among others because of that.

Is there any more information on this issue?

**Edit**: as Hellothere_1 pointed out, bullies have actually high self esteem. Hovewer some people with low self-esteem might become among others [arrogant](http://www.psychmechanics.com/2014/10/personality-traits-arrogance.html), so I guess I somehow mixed both 'traits'.

Comment: *It's not the length of your saber, it's how you use it.*

Comment: Could you add the source(s) for those quotes?

Comment: @RedCaio - No, but I can. ;)

Comment: As an English idiom, someone whose "character is lacking" doesn't typically mean that they lack *specific attributes* of character--it just means that they've got poor character, i.e. they're not a good person.

Comment: [I would like to point out that Umbridge's wand is a magnificent piece of wandscraftmanship.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dolores_Umbridge's_wand) It's a lot more detailed than pretty much any other wand I've seen, going for detail on the entire length instead of just the handle. Too bad such a beautiful wand is wasted on such an ugly person...

Comment: @Kyle Strand: +1 for interesting clarification

Comment: @Thomas Jacobs: +1 for the info. I guess that the beautiful wand is to compensate Umbridge's ugliness ;-)

Comment: She lacks the ability to be nice.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Self-awareness

Well, first, we must admit the possibility that the wand *did* choose Umbridge because of her height. Though uncommon, this does happen, presumably for the same reasons as truly long wands (ease of use).

That said, Umbridge's character is certainly very deficient. She lacks basic kindness, and she indeed has poor taste, as evidenced by her awful cat decorations. I would say, though, that **cruelty is not enough to have a short wand**. After all, the Death Eaters and Voldemort are markedly cruel, and yet they are not noted as having unusually short wands. I suspect that character flaws must be agnostic with respect to a witch or wizard's morals.

I would say that what Umbridge lacks is *self-awareness* or *self-reflection*. Unlike the Death Eaters, who entertain doubts about their cause like most people, or Voldemort, who rejects the entire notion of morality, Umbridge maintains a firm and unwavering belief in the rectitude of her own actions—a delusion so strong that, unlike most wizards and witches of her level of cruelty and malice, she can [actually produce a Patronus](https://www.reddit.com/r/PottermoreWritings/comments/3ldlvo/patronus_charm/).

> While there is a widespread and justified belief that a wizard who is
>   not pure of heart cannot produce a successful Patronus (the most
>   famous example of the spell backfiring is that of the Dark wizard
>   Raczidian, who was devoured by maggots), a rare few witches and
>   wizards of questionable morals have succeeded in producing the Charm
>   (Dolores Umbridge, for example, is able to conjure a cat Patronus to
>   protect herself from Dementors). **It may be that a true and confident
>   belief in the rightness of one's actions can supply the necessary
>   happiness.**

*That* is Dolores Umbridge's overwhelming character flaw, relative to the other witches or wizards in the series: a complete lack of introspection.

Comment: That seems right, but in my experience actually having any introspection is unusual. Unwavering belief in ones own moral righteousness seems to be the default state. With things like confirmation bias, cognitive dissonance, and many more psychological phenomena being standard and existing primarily to protect that unwavering view. If that was the case then almost everybody would be able to produce a Patronus.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich - Lack of introspection is *part* of why Umbridge can produce a Patronus. There are other requirements as well.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich - More to point, this issue is not that people think they're right - of course they do. The Death Eaters believe that they are doing the right thing by ridding wizarding society of Muggle-borns. The point is the extent to which Umbridge takes it. Ordinary people, even Death Eaters, have doubts about whether what they are doing is right. I know I do! Umbridge does not.

Comment: One thing to add would be her insistence that she is a pure blood, when she is not. Her other major flaws aside, she is ashamed of what she is and despises her ancestry, and has a pretty big identity crisis.

Comment: @SpaceOstrich (and whomever else) --  Umbridge's issue sounds more like Narcissistic Personality Disorder (or whatever they call it in Europe), as lack of introspection is also a trait of very low general intelligence. -- In regards to casting a *Patronus*, one could say her cutesy self-righteousness makes her happy enough. One might even say it makes a purrfect focus for casting a *Patronus*. :)

Comment: Having *no introspection at all* in moral terms is actually pretty weird, as being completely introspective. One can be a real a** but have at least a lonely introspection session. Most of the times, such sessions end on a self-reaffirming sentence like *yes, I'm right*. In my life I never met anyone with no introspection like Dolores. Even the most psychopatic one I met, had brief introspective moments.

Comment: I was on-board with the answer but Space Ostrich's point swayed me. I can't really see the difference in "introspection" between Umbridge and, say, Bellatrix, whose wand is 12¾". Either they both evaluate themselves and say "Yes, I'm right" or neither of them do, depending on how far you wanna take the assumption/what we mean with introspection. I think they both equally approve of their own behaviour, so I don't see the wand length coming into play there.

Comment: Introspection or extrospection (seeking external or societal evidence or information)? Meaning her nihilism is so great she has no acknowledgement of anyone outside herself as other than a thing, an object. I do that sometimes and is the leading cause of my dickishness, not recognizing another person's autonomy. Cat stuff also suggests lack of emotional development. My sister had her elephant thing or other animal phases where she collected all sorts of trinkets based on them until she got into a serious emotional/romantic relationship. Then it just stopped.

Comment: Rollo May in _Courage to Create_ discusses **doubt** as what defines courage; [tension between conviction and doubt as the foundation of the highest form of courage](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/one-among-many/201602/rollo-may-and-the-courage-create). Uncertainty is a fearful state for people and those that act or think without doubt attempt to make the world conform to their view and not adding to the world, creating a synthesis of will and reality that benefits all. Genius = smart person with doubt, Tyrant = smarts w/out doubt. Being human means balancing cognitive and emotional...

Answer (score 5):

I don't actually think so.

In fiction bullies are often depicted as unsure confidence lacking people who try to mask their lack of self esteem with cruelty.

Studies show that this has little foothold in reality. Unsure people might join in on an already existing bullying situation, but the ringleaders almost always have high self esteem and simply enjoy being cruel.

I am pretty sure this holds true for Umbridge.

I actually speak a bit from experience here since my French teacher in 8th and 9th grade had an uncanny resemblance to Umbridge, from the obvious enjoyment of cruelty and mobbing right down to the weird clothing style and extreme love of cats.
I don't think she would have lowered herself to blood quills and executing muggleborn, but you never know.

What I'm saying here is that Umbridge is not some weird fantasy that Rowling came up with, but very much based on some real personality type. (Likely Rowling knew someone like her)

Coming back to your question I don't feel like my teacher was consciously compensating for something. In fact, I don't think she even recognized her own actions as cruel or unjust.

In every class she would pick a few victims and try to tear them apart at every chance given, but at the same time when talking with the class as a whole, parents on parent conference day, or generally any person she had no direct power over, she tended act as if she genuinely believed to be the nicest and most caring teacher on earth.

I have never seen her show any bit of remorse, regret, or even just a recognition of her own misdemeanor.

Since Umbridge in the books is identical to her in every other aspect I don't see why she would be different in that regard.

Comment: This is all very true.  But what do you mean by
"I don't actually think so"? Also,  do you think the characteristics you mentioned  are related  to the length of Umbridge's wand?

Comment: I don't think that Umbridge is lacking self esteem or confidence. Lack of self esteem can certainly lead to short outbursts of cruelty (Everybody always walked over me, so why should I not walk over others now that I have the chance), but long term cruelty like Umbridge displays it usually stems from too much confidence and a sense of superiority. She is not that different from most Death Eaters in that regard, many of whom have long wands. I think the the short wand is more meant to play at the fact that she is magically impotent (as cringe-worthy as that sounds)

Comment: I guess in part I mixed being a bully with other traits like arrogance. Or maybe being weak with having a low self esteem.  What you explained about your teacher and Umbridge self reminds me a bit about a roommate who also had a poor taste and poor behaviour. The main difference is that she was more arrogant than a bully, plus she told me once she has a low self esteem.

Comment: Could you include links to some of the studies about high self esteem in bullies?

Comment: I had a really hard time finding some actual data on the subject. I did however find this article here http://www.parentingscience.com/pure-bullies.html which is a good summary of the stuff I was originally taught at school.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily disagreeing with explanations given above, I have another suggestion. It comes from the choice of the first name, Dolores. This is thought to derive from "Virgin Mary of sorrows". Dolor means sorrow. Perhaps the author has meant that Umbridge is made out of sorrow, and indeed (as noticed above) derives surrogate happiness as a sort of self esteem when doling out sorrow to others with a show of virtue.
If the sorrow-substance idea is of any substance, Umbridge has found herself throughout life curiously incapable of even wishing for happiness and thinks happiness is a feeble drug pursued by vain and empty people. Any sign of enthousiasm as a potential beginning of happiness should be suppressed.
So for my two bits, Rowling portrays a caricature of the idea of the virgin of sorrows as many may exist in catholic schools in the person of a teaching or governing nun, the type you can expect to rise to a managerial position (here I should apologise to those who are different).
I think it is wrong to think Umbridge has no empathy or selfawareness. She has loads - just not the kind you and I would wish for. If I am right, this may come straight from Rowlings own (early?) experience. No empathy or selfawareness are simply too feeble to conjure up the total evil that she embodies at a vital phase of the narrative.
Brrrr